# BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization in WinRT

Tags: asynchronous, windows-runtime, observablecollection

I am writing a Windows 8 store application where I have a view model that contains a rather large observable collection. Every once in a while we get an event from the model that causes us to start a pretty long process to update the observable collection. It works great, except that currently the process is running in the UI thread and is locking the UI for a few seconds, which is a pretty bad practice for UI development...

I wanted to move the heavy calculation into a task, so that the calculations are made without blocking the UI and the updates to the observable collection are done one at a time on the UI thread. in WPF there is a mechanism that allows to do exactly that using the following code in the view model constructor:

```
var myLock = new object();
var myList = new ObservableCollection<ItemType>();
BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(myList, myLock);
```

and then wrapping each update to the observable collection in a lock block. I tried to do the same in WinRT but it appears that BindingOperations does not have this method there.

Is there any acceptable best practice to accomplish the same thing in WinRT?

Thnx,